# Erro ao executar function em outro arquivo

Tags: php

Dentro do arquivo inserir.php eu tenho uma função que valida o envio para o banco e logo apos envia um email de retorno, o problema que ao marcar o arquivo envia.php que ira executar o codigo da o seguinte erro.

Fatal error: Call to undefined method email::envioemail() in

Segue:

inserir.php

```
include("envia.php");
$envia=new email();
$envia->envioemail();
```

envio.php

```
class email {
function enviaemail() {
```

Comment: `envioemail` para `enviaemail`, é um **o** por um **a**.

Comment: O nome do arquivo no include também está errado. Dica: Nome de classe começa com letra maiúscula, e melhor declarar sempre o escopo de um método.

Comment: Kkkkkkk não acredito. O arquivo tá certo. Eu escrivão errado ali. Depois do almoço eu testo.

Comment: está invocando "envioemail()" sendo que o nome do método é "enviaemail()".. percebe o erro? trocou a letra "a" pela letra "o".

Comment: Sim. kkk era esse o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe alguns erros no código. Deveria estar mais ou menos assim:
*Estrutura dos arquivos*

```
SeuProjeto  
|--inserir.php 
|--class //folder
|-------Envio.php
```

Com isso seu código ficaria assim:
*inserir.php*

```
include("class/Envio.php");
$envia = new email();
$envia->envioemail();
```

*Envio.php*

```
class email 
{
   function envioemail() 
   {
     //SUA FUNÇÃO AQUI
   }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Então eu setava a função enviaemail(), e no outro arquivo a função estava envioemail(). Era só esse o erro. Obrigado.